# Scala for Android - "not a directory" error in IntelliJ Idea when attempting to build

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm getting an error whenever I try to compile my Scala-based Android project in Intellij Idea.

> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module (dependency)
>
> Information:javac 1.8.0_131 was used to compile java sources
>
> Error:java:
> C:\Users\username.android\sbt\exploded-aars\(dependency)\classes.jar:
> not a directory

where (dependency) is a Java module pulled in via SBT that Java is attempting to compile. I don't think it is related to any specific dependency, but I've seen this error happen with two dependencies so far:

- com.github.satyan-sugar-1.5
- com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-25.4.0

This error does not occur if the project is compiled in SBT at the command line.

I have tried updating Java, IntelliJ, SBT, and my plugins. I also tried ensuring that SBT was not running in the console in my project's directory when compiling occurred. These things did not help at all.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: This may not be SBT after all. While the configuration is set up to use android:package on build via SBT, there is no indication in the error log that the module compilation was done through it.

**EDIT 2**: It seems to be a result of how either IntelliJ or the SBT plugin likes to put all of its dependencies in as an IntelliJ module with the project's modules. If you delete all of the dependency modules, the error goes away and new errors can arise. If you then refresh your SBT dependencies using the SBT plugin window, the modules are restored--and so is the error.

Comment: It seems there are .jar files where IntelliJ expects directories.

Comment: Yeah, but why does IntelliJ expect directories there when straight SBT is completely cool with the module structure and can compile them?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. SBT and IntelliJ are completely separated tools with completely different configurations.

Comment: I was talking about IntelliJ calling the SBT command android:package in order to build, as is the standard configuration for Scala for Android. But upon further consideration that may be irrelevant here. I'm not sure it gets to that step now since IntelliJ doesn't say it's an SBT error. My bad.